My production iOS app mysteriously has a "beta" label on it
In my flutter app, I've previously released my apps to production with generally no issues.
In my recent workflows, I've since upgraded flutter to 3.19.5, and added a new step in my Fastfile:
app_store_connect_api_key(
  key_id: ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_KEY_ID"],
  issuer_id: ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_ISSUER_ID"],
  key_content: ENV["APP_STORE_CONNECT_API_KEY_KEY"],
  is_key_content_base64: true,
  duration: 500
)

Since then, my production app has been uploading with a beta label:

in the image, I wanted to illustrate the previous version that didn't have that label, and now, in my latest version, it does. I've tried updating the icons in my Runner > Assets > AppIcons to the ones without the beta label but it still seems to upload with said label.
How do I remove this?
